# dynamic database connection sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a simple database connection in nodejs sequelize like following:

```js
let sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
```

Now I want that `config.database` to be dynamic, this database name should come from user route.

Like:

```js
router.route("/route-name", (req, res) => {
    const database_name = req.query.database_name;
    // change connection
    // get data from table
});
```

Is there any possible way to change database connection after creating connection in sequelize?